# Alternative to ROW_NUMBER() to get row position?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a dynamically generated query with a potentially complex `ORDER BY` clause. I need to retrieve the row number into a column for further processing. All the documentation I've been able to find points me to `ROW_NUMBER()` but —unless I'm missing something— I need to rewrite the query to move the `ORDER BY` clause from this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

... to this:

```
SELECT ..., ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...) AS RN
FROM ...
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
```

I can certainly do that but it involves tweaking some convoluted code that's shared by other modules that do not need this.

Is there a variable of function that just retrieves row position in current result set?

Comment: I think you need to set up a cursor.

Comment: There is no pseudo column for a row position in SQL Server (as in other DBMS). The simplest solution is the one you mentioned, using the row number function correctly ordered.

Comment: @Kiel Oh, thanks. I haven't worked with cursors but, from what I've gathered in a quick doc peek, that involves writing a stored procedure. In my case, that makes the code rewrite bigger than just using `ROW_NUMER()`. :_(

Comment: Does the further processing take place in T-SQL, or in client code?

Comment: @lad2025 In this specific situation I don't really need to sort (I just need to know the row position) but it's totally correct.

Comment: @EdHarper So far it all happens in a huge single query that populates a temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach I've seen people use is the following:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempresult') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #tempresult;
CREATE TABLE #tempresult (
    idx INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    ...
);

INSERT #tempresult ...
SELECT ...
FROM ...
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

`idx` is actually what we look for.
However, not sure if this would be more performance optimal. Depends on your cases.
The temp table could be replaced with table variable if necessary, and also a `PRIMARY KEY` on `idx` could be used.

Generally I would always go for `ROW_NUMBER()` as it is overall the better option.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. I couldn't find official documentation but there's a [blog post from year 2005](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2005/07/20/ordering-guarantees-in-sql-server/) that suggests the order of `IDENTITY` is guaranteed to match that of `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
select  *, row_number() over(order by (select null))
from    MyTable
order by Col1
```

The `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause is seperate from the `ORDER BY` clause for the query.

`order by (select null)` gets round the problem of having to supply a column for ordering the row_number() function.

If you have concerns about performance, you should do some testing for your situation and post another question if there is a problem.

Comment: This seems to work surprisingly well. I'd appreciate some additional explanations on how it works, how reliable it is and what performance concerns there may be.

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to number according to final presentation order. All rows are tied for the ordering value so any distribution of numbering would be correct. In practice I'm not sure it would be possible to come up with an example where it doesn't work as desired though.

Comment: An example where the ordering is as desired but the numbering probably isn't is `SELECT row_number() over(order by (select null))
FROM sys.objects
ORDER BY name
OFFSET 4 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY` as row number 1 in the resultset starts at 5

Comment: @MartinSmith I think I understand what you mean. There can be a specific query in a specific SQL Server version where query optimiser can suddenly realise that it's faster to assign values to `row_number()` before sorting the overall set and results will still comply with the specs.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - yes. At least in theory. As all rows are tied for the ordering value so no deterministic behaviour is guaranteed for this case. A 5 row result set could be numbered `1,3,4,2,5` in theory and that would be equally correct

Comment: @Martin Smith:  Good point!  Perhaps applying the `row_number()` in an outer query may be the correct route?

Answer (score 0):

For the records, this precise feature does not seem to be implemented in SQL Server at the time of writing, not even in latest versions. You need to use other techniques like [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or the temporary table trick explained in the accepted answer.

*(Oracle, for instance, has the [ROWNUM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns008.htm) pseudo-column.)*